# Eclipse Oxygen Plugin Feature export fails for Java 9

Tags: eclipse-plugin, java-9, eclipse-jdt

Exporting Eclipse plugin feature using the export wizard results in the following error.

> Eclipse Compiler for Java(TM) v20171123-1049, 3.13.100, Copyright IBM
>   Corp 2000, 2015. All rights reserved. option -bootclasspath not
>   supported at compliance level 9 and above

This is the latest Eclipse and JDK installation, is there any solution/workaround for this compilation problem?

**Edit:**

Eclipse feature export succeeds if we select the

> "Use class files  compiled in the workspace" checkbox

in "Options" tab of the "Export Wizard".

Comment: The work on Java 9 support for Eclipse Plugin Development is still in progress, I think. For example, this bug was resolved three days ago: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=514471

Comment: This is related to Eclipse bug [525280](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=525280)

Comment: Running into this problem myself. Anyone find a workaround yet?

Answer (score 1):

In my case [this comment from the Eclipse bug tracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=525280#c19) has proven useful:

> we have noticed that the "option -bootclasspath not supported at compliance level 9 and above" happens in 2019-03 and -06 only for projects that have NO "Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment" defined in their MANIFEST.MF.
>
> As soon as you add this setting, the error goes away. The setting just needs to be there, it does not matter whether the value is JavaSE-12 or even -8 .

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using JDK 11. I face the same issue

- [javac] option -bootclasspath not supported at compliance level 9 and
  above

I have added this below line in MANIFEST.MF file and it worked.

```
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-11
```